# Call method when ObservableProperty changes using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm

Tags: c#, observablecollection, community-toolkit-mvvm

I'm implementing auto complete feature in my .NET MAUI app and I'm using `CommunityToolkit.Mvvm` code generators in my view model to handle observable properties.

I have the following code and I'm trying call `GetSuggestions()` method when the `SearchText` changes.

```
[ObservableProperty]
[NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(GetSuggestions))]
string searchText;

[ObservableProperty]
bool showSuggestions;

ObservableCollection<string> Suggestions { get; } = new();

private async Task GetSuggestions()
{
   if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchText) || SearchText.Length < 3)
      return;

   var data = await _myApiService.GetSuggestions(SearchText.Trim());
   if(data != null && data.Count > 0)
   {
      Suggestions.Clear();
      foreach(var item in data)
         Suggestions.Add(item);

      ShowSuggestions = true;
   }
}
```

This is giving me the following error:

> The target(s) of [NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor] must be an accessible
> IRelayCommand property, but "GetSuggestions" has no matches in type
> MyViewModel.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess there are two problems here.

#### Why is this error occurring?

That happens because `GetSuggestions` is not a Command.
Try adding the `[RelayCommand]` attribute to your method.

```
[RelayCommand]
private async Task GetSuggestions()
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchText) || SearchText.Length < 3)
       return;

    var data = await _myApiService.GetSuggestions(SearchText.Trim());
    if(data != null && data.Count > 0)
    {
        Suggestions.Clear();
        foreach(var item in data)
        Suggestions.Add(item);

        ShowSuggestions = true;
    }
}
```

Then link `NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor` to the autogenerated command.

```
[ObservableProperty]
[NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(GetSuggestionsCommand))]
string searchText;
```

#### The second one.

You need to

> call GetSuggestions() method when the SearchText changes.

The `NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor` attribute doesn't do that.

In the autogenerated source code you should find an empty partial method called `OnSearchTextPropertyChanged`. Try implementing it.

```
partial void OnSearchTextPropertyChanged(string value)
{
    GetSuggestions();
}
```

If this is what you're searching for, `GetSuggestions` doesn't need to be marked with the `RelayCommand` attribute.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Very useful indeed. A follow up question if I may: the `GetSuggestions()` is an `async` method. If I make it `partial void OnSearchTextPropertyChanged()` it works but it complains that I'm not awaiting `GetSugestions()`. It works fine though. Do I not need to `await` the call to `GetSuggestions()` method inside the `OnSearchTextPropertyChanged()` method?

Comment: Glad to hear that. You can mark the partial method as `async` so that you can await code inside its body. `partial async void OnSearchTextPropertyChanged(string value)
{
     await GetSuggestions();
}`. It all depends on what you need to do.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't like it when I add `async` to the method. When it's `partial async void OnSearchTextPropertyChanged(string value)`, it gives me an error. I also tried changing it to `partial async Task OnSearchTextPropertyChanged(string value)` and it doesn't like that either.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I switched the keywords. It should work with `async partial void ...`

Comment: While most of this was helpful, I need to do a few things different including using the `[RelayCommand]` and calling the method inside my OnPropChanged method to be `Task.Run(() => this.MyMethodAsync()).Wait();`. See my answer as more of a partial or ammendment to this one.

Answer (score 0):

Only meant as more of an amendment of @RMinato's answer.

As my comment say: "While most of this was helpful, I need to do a few things different including using the `[RelayCommand]` and calling the method inside my `OnPropChanged` method to be `Task.Run(() => this.MyMethodAsync()).Wait();`".

My code looks like:

```
[QueryProperty(nameof(Course), nameof(Course))]
public partial class CourseDetailViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private readonly CourseService courseService;

    public CourseDetailViewModel(CourseService courseService)
    {
        this.courseService = courseService;
    }

    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(GetCourseDetailCommand))]
    Course course;

    partial void OnCourseChanged(Course value)
    {
        Task.Run(() => this.GetCourseDetailAsync()).Wait();
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    public async Task GetCourseDetailAsync()
    {
        if (GetCourseDetailCommand.IsRunning) return;

        try
        {
            IsBusy = true;

            course = await courseService.GetCourseDetailAsync(course.Id);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Failed to get course detail. Error: {ex.Message}");
            await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Error!",
                $"Failed to get course detail: {ex.Message}", "OK");
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Adam. As I said in my answer, for the specific case or the author `NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor` wasn't really needed. I don't know if you're trying to define some more complex scenarios where you call `GetCourseDetailAsync` both as a command and as a normal method and  change executability of it as a command. I find this kind of behavior weird, honestly. Anyway, are you sure you really need that `Task.Run(() => this.GetCourseDetailAsync()).Wait();`? The `Wait` method for a `Task` is something that's usually not wanted because it blocks everything occurring in current Task, possibly even UI